# query de sistema de encuesta usuarios con mayor peso que otro - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

necesito ayuda, actualmente estoy trabajando en un sistema de encuestas (realizado en PHP y MYSQL) y estoy modificando la consulta para la grafica que mostrara los resultados

el tema es que en dicha votación de cada pregunta unos usuarios tendrán mas peso que otros al momento de votar, en mi tabla usuarios tengo los siguientes campos

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `porcentaje_participacion` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id_usuario`,`clave`,`nombres`,`apellidos`,`email`,`id_tipo_usuario`,`porcentaje_participacion`) VALUES
('admin', 'admin', 'Administrador', 'AD', 'admin@correo.com', '1', '0'),
('303167', '123', 'Marco', 'Chavez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '50'),
('301663', '123', 'Mauren', 'Martinez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303344', '123', 'Neidy', 'Osorto', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303203', '123', 'Jorge', 'Martinez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303314', '123', 'Sonia', 'Sorto', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '20');
```

Donde el campo **porcentaje_participacion** es el campo en el que esta el peso del voto del usuario

por ejemplo ya tengo una pregunta lanzada, y tengo este query

```
SELECT 
        preguntas.id_pregunta, 
        encuestas.titulo,
        opciones.valor,
        resultados.id_usuario,
        usuarios.porcentaje_participacion
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = 6

        ORDER BY opciones.valor
```

El cual me arroja el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí todo bien, lo único que me falta es un campo mas con el calculo que definirá la grafica, el cual es dependiendo el peso que tenga cada usuario en la votacion, hice la formula en excel la cual seria el porcentaje de participacion * suma de usuarios que votaron entre 100

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como plasmarlo en la consulta,

Alguien que me ayude

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta de abajo, recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que otros puedan utilizarla...Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Buen Día...

En el `SELECT` de tu consulta, coloca un campo con el factor de multiplicación (la formula entre los campos y la división entre 100) y le das un alias y lo puedes utilizar en tu resultado.

Aquí el Ejemplo según tu código:

```
SELECT 
        preguntas.id_pregunta, 
        encuestas.titulo,
        opciones.valor,
        resultados.id_usuario,
        usuarios.porcentaje_participacion,
        ((usuarios.porcentaje_participacion * opciones.valor / 100)) as Valor_con_Peso
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = 6

        ORDER BY Valor_con_Peso
```

...y el `ORDER BY` sería ahora por "Valor_con_Peso"

**IMPORTANTE**: Para que te funcione la operación matemática debes cambiar el tipo de campo a numérico en la Base de datos en la tabla usuario, porque lo tienes como string por lo que estoy viendo en tú pregunta ---> `porcentaje_participacion` varchar(10).

Por último, te recomiendo reforzar tus conocimientos en cuanto a la creación de Bases de Datos, tablas y campos, ya que veo algunas incongruencias, ejemplo de ello si tienes "Id de usuario" veo que son todos numericos menos el que dice "admin" pero es un gran costo a nivel de procesamiento colocar string a ese campo solo por ese usuario en particular, es preferible pasar ese campo a numerico y crear un campo que lo identifique como "admin" o utilizar el que ya tienes creado llamado "id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL".

Comment: Le realice unos cambios a la formula la cual quedo asi 
```((usuarios.porcentaje_participacion*100)/SUM(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion)) as count```y me muestra exacto el resultado en base al porcentaje de participacion, pero solo me muestra un dato, me faltan los otros 2 de las otras opciones, no si se sera que tengo que agrupar

Comment: ```SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta, encuestas.titulo,opciones.valor,resultados.id_usuario,usuarios.porcentaje_participacion,((usuarios.porcentaje_participacion*100)/SUM(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion)) as count
FROM opciones 
INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = 1 GROUP BY preguntas.id_pregunta ORDER BY opciones.valor```

Comment: @MarcoTulio Solo hemos agregado una fórmula y colocado un alias, antes te traía todos o solo uno, porque al agregar la fórmula no afecta el select original que colocaste, por favor comprueba tu select.